# Embedding Apps with API key

Tags: rally

I am attempting to follow instructions inside https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps to utilize a alm-wsapi-read-only API key.  I created a simple defect query app using the rally-app-builder.  When I am logged out of Rally, I try to view the defect grid using the following syntax in the Chrome browser, where I insert my apiKey in place of "key here":

file:///C:/ProjectWork/RallyGitHub/rally-app-defect-metrics/deploy/App-external.html?apiKey="key here"

When loading this page asks me for my Rally login credentials instead of defaulting to the Rally user embedded in the API key.

Any help on what I am doing incorrectly?

The app code is as follows in this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DefectMetrics</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define("CustomApp",{extend:"Rally.app.App",componentCls:"app",launch:function(){Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({type:"Defect",success:function(model){this.grid=this.add({xtype:"rallygrid",model:model,columnCfgs:["FormattedID","Name","State","Owner"],storeConfig:{filters:[{property:"State",operator:"=",value:"Closed"}]}})},scope:this})}});

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name:"DefectMetrics",
            parentRepos:""
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When accessed through a file:// URL, AppSDK2.0rc3 apps use JSONP:

[image: File URL screenshot]

Which doesn't allow setting an API key in the request header, so you're prompted for credentials through basic auth.

When run through `rally-app-builder run` as described in the [Embedding Apps help document](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps), you're running through a node.js server, allowing AppSDK2 to use CORS, and the apiKey can be set as needed in the request header to Rally.

Note that `rally-app-builder run` will initially bring up:

```
http://localhost:1337/App-debug.html
```

in your default browser, which will prompt you for credentials. However, if you manually append your api key to the URL:

```
http://localhost:1337/App-debug.html?apiKey=_m9XjyrgVQ6
```

and refresh, the app will render without the need to enter credentials.