# Getting Rally API key to work outside of rally App

Tags: rally

I have seen this question and response, but it still does not work for us: 
[Embedding Apps with API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289742/embedding-apps-with-api-key)

We are having a problem with the Rally API. Our intent is to make a stand-alone page (outside of Rally) that shows the portfolio Kanban.

I have attached the test page. It was created with the rally-app-builder. We created an API key. When we try to load the page, passing the API key, we get a json exception about cross-site violations. The documentation says that we will see this error if we don't pass the key. But even when we do pass it, the error persists.

We have tried it through an apache server, so the issue about being a standalone file is not our problem. Does anyone have any other ideas?

The html page is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>helloworld</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define("CustomApp",{extend:"Rally.app.App",componentCls:"app",items:{html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},launch:function(){this.add({xtype:"rallycardboard",types:["Portfolio Item/Feature"],attribute:"State",storeConfig:{context:{project:"/project/14292239482",projectScopeUp:!1,projectScopeDown:!0}},context:this.getContext(),readOnly:!0})}});

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"helloworld",
             parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The api key we generated is of type alm-wsapi-read-only. When page is loaded, even with apikey parameter provided, we get the JSON x-site error.

We are wondering if there is a config  to change on Rally subscription side or perhaps there is an error in the documentation or something else simple.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a defect. It works up to the point when I load an App-debug.html using rally-app-builder run command:

```
rab run
```

and append apiKey to the app's URL as a query parameter. It loads fine using the apiKey:

[image]

The problem starts when I choose a different server to load an embedded app, for example:

a)start a simple http python or node server in another directory

b)copy App-external.html from deploy folder to the directory from which the server is running

c)create a new file, App-embedded.html in this directory :

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>Embedded app test: revs</title>
  </header>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:9000/App-external.html?apiKey=_Ib4u6d7"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

d)load App-embedded.html

These steps results in cross-origin error.

If you check in Chrome's Network tab, or Safari debugger it shows that artifact   (hierarchicalrequirement or defect) requests fails. Interestingly, the preceding subscription, user and schema requests complete successfully. Screenshot from Safari:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the underlying issues were related to the CORS configuration on the Rally servers, not anything specific with App SDK 2.0rc3.  As of 11/24/14 this issue should be resolved.